# Интерполяция матрицы

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Как интерполировать текущую матрицу? Известно, что ее строки линии линейно зависимы. Второй вектор больше первого в 3,8 раза, а третий больше второго в 1,36 раза.

```
import numpy as np
lst = [[0.0, 9.65482234954834, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4392.50146484375, 4413.01416015625, 4279.15673828125, 4441.95751953125, 4356.40185546875, 4216.439453125, 4320.54736328125, 4313.57470703125, 4358.31298828125, 4172.80615234375, 4207.71875], 
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15338.384765625, 15798.109375, 15535.3623046875, 16247.1298828125, 16105.185546875, 15691.068359375, 15853.0869140625, 15678.134765625, 15474.01171875, 15799.8740234375, 15546.822265625], 
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22739.58203125, 22782.068359375, 22920.478515625, 23990.54296875, 23933.31640625, 23497.22265625, 23257.619140625, 23750.544921875, 22999.19921875, 22714.302734375, 22839.28125]]
array = np.array(lst)
array[array == 0] = np.nan
```

Лучшее, что вышло у меня (в формате df, потому что я использую Pandas):

```
  Value_S10  Value_S11    Value_S12     Value_S13     Value_S14  \
0        NaN   9.654822  1105.366483   2201.078144   3296.789804   
1        NaN  36.688325  3862.112435   7687.536545  11512.960655   
2        NaN  49.896122  5722.317599  11394.739077  17067.160554   

      Value_S15     Value_S16     Value_S17      Value_S2      Value_S3  \
0   4392.501465   4413.014160   4279.156738   4441.957520   4356.401855   
1  15338.384766  15798.109375  15535.362305  16247.129883  16105.185547   
2  22739.582031  22782.068359  22920.478516  23990.542969  23933.316406   

       Value_S4      Value_S5      Value_S6      Value_S7      Value_S8  \
0   4216.439453   4320.547363   4313.574707   4358.312988   4172.806152   
1  15691.068359  15853.086914  15678.134766  15474.011719  15799.874023   
2  23497.222656  23257.619141  23750.544922  22999.199219  22714.302734   

       Value_S9  
0   4207.718750  
1  15546.822266  
2  22839.281250
```

Все nan требуется заменить разумными значениями. У меня не полностью вышло избавился от nan. Нужна помощь

Comment: "Второй вектор больше первого в 3,8 раза, а третий больше второго в 1,36 раза." - наверное, все таки "ЗНАЧЕНИЯ второго вектора больше ЗНАЧЕНИЙ первого в 3.8 раза, а ЗНАЧЕНИЯ третьего больше ЗНАЧЕНИЙ второго в 1,36 раза". Но это условие не выполняется для вашего примера. Почему?

Comment: Это коэффиценты которые я определил. Имеется ввиду что примерно во столько раз. И да, именно значения